# How to defend myself from the accusation of being rude.?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [&& and || are not logical but conditional operators?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361112/and-are-not-logical-but-conditional-operators/361194#361194)

I would like to know how to defend myself from the accusation of being rude.

I know that Stack Exchange is a multicultural portal, where people of different linguistic knowledge of the English grammar and semantics try to communicate about technical aspects of Software Engineering.

Unfortunately, I'm not a native speaker of English, and as such I may be inaccurate at times. But up to now, I'm not considered a rude person in any part of the world that I lived or worked. And I would be very sad if the good people of Software Engineering Stack Exchange start to consider me rude.

The question in point was about terminology -- the OP met some unusual terminology, and like any programmer would, he felt doubt about it.

Fortunately, I met this unusual terminology before, and solved my doubt about it. And was willing to share my experience with the OP.

To clarify the unusual terminology, I used very basic, trivial examples. That kind of thing may disgust some people that may understand basic examples as an insult to their technical knowledge, while au contraire, they're just there to avoid creating unnecessary noise. So, I tried to tell that programmers should not be disgusted at examples as basic as the ones I used, and should concentrate in my effort to clarify the terminology.

But unfortunately, one of the readers mistook my idea completely and understood that my mention of "any programmer" was an insult to the knowledge of the OP. And he kept insisting that I was rude, even when other readers stated that it didn't seem to be my intention.

I would like to apologize for my imprecision. And to praise the high standards of human behavior in Software Engineering Stack Exchange community.

I am disgusted when I see people mistreating others in any part of the world. Particularly in technical exchanges, conceived to share knowledge, and not bad moods. So, I ask you to please do not consider me a rude person.

Answer (score 1):

The user who called your answer "rude" probably misunderstood the intentions of your answer, so my recommendation here is, don't overthink this. To me your answer does not sound rude. BUT - to me, your answer sounds like missing the point of the OPs question (and I hope, saying that does not sound too rude in your ears ;-)

Comment: Hello, Doc Brown ! I am really pleased to meet you. 
:-D 

Having watched your films, I would never say you're rude... 

I think that answers here should be much shorter and more schematic, so anyone can clearly see what you're trying to say. I will do this in another time. I will also try to be more focused on the OP question too.

Thanks for your wise (and enlightening) comments.